# How to iterate through json files in folder and convert them to csv files in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have 79 files from the folder that I want to load these and bring them into Python. I plan on converting these to csv files. Is it better to append all the json files into 1 file then convert to CSV in one large file? Or convert each json individually into a csv file then append the csv file together?

This is what I have so far. What am I missing?

```
import os 
file = r'C:\Users\data\CDER4.json'

def openfile(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        cdmfile = json.load(f)
    return cdmfile

cvmfile = openfile(r'C:\Users\data\CDER4.json')
```

Comment: I think later is memory efficient. You read the JSON files and convert them to CSV iteratively and just `append` the existing CSV file. It will not take all the data in the memory at a single point in time.

Comment: what is the structure of the json files? asre they all the same?

Comment: Yes @TenaciousB They are all the same format.

Comment: can you post an example of one of the json files?